# how to change plot sizing in R

Tags: r, plot, pie-chart

I have a collection of pie graphs that I am trying to put in a 2x2 array, but the image is distorted; how can I change the size?

```
x1 <- c(90,7,3)
x2 <- c(70,18,12)
x3 <- c(17,4,30,17,30) 

label1 <- c('Physically 90%','Spoke 7%','Never 3%')
label2 <- c('Abrupt Stop 70%','Go Around 18%','Stops Far \nAway 12%')
label3 <- c('None 17','Robot-Robot 4%','Robot-\nHuman 30%','Robot-\nObject 17%','Robot-\nSurface 30%')


par(mfrow = c(2,2)) 

pie(x1, label1,main="Instances Where Robot Has Been Stuck", col=rainbow(length(x1)))
pie(x2, label2,main="How Robot Avoids Objects", col=rainbow(length(x2)))
pie(x3, label3,main="Collision Types", col=rainbow(length(x3)))
```

Comment: Are perhaps failing to set the aspect ratio?

Comment: Please specify what exactly is your problem and what is your desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can add some code to an initial code chunk if you're using R Markdown:

```
library(knitr)

opts_chunk$set(fig.width=8, fig.height=8)
```

fig width and height should be the answer, or:

````
```{r fig.width=8, fig.height=8}
````

This will work for individual code chunks in R markdown